# Prove that an even order ($n=2k$) graph without cycle of order 3, has a size $m \le k^2$

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing, induction, bipartite-graphs

Let *G* be a graph of order *n* and size *m* that does not have any cycle of length 3. Prove that if  $n=2k$, then $m \le k^2$.

How should I go about proving this? I can use either induction, contradiction, or contrapositive. When I asked my teacher for help, she said that since graph *G* cannot have any cycle of length three, we will assume that graph *G* is bipartite, because 3 is an odd cycle and a bipartite graph cannot have an odd cycle. But this doesn't make sense to me because can't we have a cycle of 5? or 7? Please help.

Comment: Thanks Stefan and bat_of_doom, I really appreciate the suggestions, but I was wondering if there was any way to prove through either induction, contradiction, or contrapositive methods. We really haven't gone too in-depth into graph theory, so these are the methods I'm familiar with. Thanks!

Comment: Induction is what I thought of initially, based on your suggestion . But the problem  you face in trying to solve the problem by induction is that you need to have an upper bound on the least degree of the graph, e.g. suppose $\delta (G) \leq 3$ were true. Then it is quite easy to solve this by using induction hypothesis. But the problem is that such a bound need not hold. I was stuck on this for hours, constructed non-trivial counter examples with $\delta(G) \geq 4$ and no 3-cycles and finally gave up on induction.

Comment: Contrapositive or contradiction is not really very easy on this problem. For example you may want to look at Ramsey theory from combinatorics which is filled with problems with a similar flavor (if $m \geq \frac{n^2}{2}$ then the graph must have a 3 cycle), and it is has no obvious approaches in general. So, I finally hit upon this direct proof. If you understood either one of our answers, please make sure to accept one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of this general theorem that Stefan posts about. Here's a combinatorial approach:
For now, assume $3|n$.  We shall handle the 2 special cases later. Divide the vertices into sets of 3. Any set of 3 vertices has atmost 2 edges in it.
Consider any two such sets. There can be atmost 5 edges that can pass between these two sets, if both of them contain 2 edges. Hence, the total number of edges is bounded by: 
$$m \leq \frac{2*n}{3}+5* \binom{\frac{n}{3}}{2}$$
From here you can get that this is bounded above by $\frac{n^2}{4}$. I hope you can argue out the rest of the cases, which should have a similar reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

By [Mantel's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tur%C3%A1n%27s_theorem#Mantel%27s_theorem) we have that any triangle-free graph has at most $\left[ \frac{n^2}{4} \right] = k^2$ edges. From here we conclude that $m \le k^2$

To prove the Mantel's Theorem we consider the sums of degrees $d(w) + d(v)$, where $wv \in E(G)$. If there's no triangle, then we have that $d(w) + d(v) \le n$, so $$\sum d(v)^2 = \sum_{vw \in E(G)} d(v) + d(w) \le mn$$

On the other side by Handshake's Lemma and Cauchy-Schwartz Inequality we have:

$$\sum d(v)^2 \ge \frac 1n \left(\sum d(v)\right)^2 = \frac{4m^2}{n}$$

From this two inequalies we determine that $mn \ge \frac{4m^2}{n} \implies m \le \frac{n^2}{4}$